# Show application gateway probes on Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-gateway, azure-oms

In our landscape we've got a couple of web application gateways deployed with probes set-up to back-end services. In the resource panes of the gateways there is the "Backend Health" option that you can use to check the health state of your back-ends, which is very nice.

Now we were building some dashboards and we wanted to include the same status overview on one of those. I couldn't find a way to do that. Of course there's Azure monitor which you can use to also check the status but I'd then have two solutions doing exactly the same thing just because I need the data to surface on a dashboard. That doesn't feel right.

So the question is; does anyone know of a better way to do this, or am I really bound to the alternative option of monitoring twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Alerts if the probes goes down. As of now, Probe health is not exposed to Dashboards. Please raise a User voice to get it added in the future: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback?query=dashboard